# my function not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**php newbie**

I created a function to handle my image location but unfortunately it's not working and show no errors. Hopefully, someone share there idea why my function not working.

```
function image_path($number){
  get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/image{$number}.gif";
  return $number;
}
```

Comment: try return get_template_directory_uri() ."/images/image{$number}.gif";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is quite odd, as you're taking a variable in the arguments, then returning that variable back directly without doing anything to it.

This would make more sense:

```
function image_path($number) { 
  return get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/image{$number}.gif";
}
```

Then later call it and directly output its return:

```
<img src="<?php echo image_path(123) ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are calling the function like this...

```
echo image_path($someNumber);
```

Your function would look like this:

```
function image_path($number){
  return get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/image{$number}.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use echo, like this:

```
function image_path($number){
  echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/image{$number}.gif";
  return $number;
}
```

Comment: It's sloppy practice to just stick echoes inside of function calls like this. You're also ignoring that $number is passed in, never updated, and returned back.

Comment: I completely agree with you, however, it is valid.